# elixir phoenix - put_flash/3 in the plug

Tags: elixir, plug, phoenix-live-view

I created a `plug` to check if the user already created a profile, and redirect them to the `/profiles/new` page with a flash if they not yet have one:

**Plug.CheckProfile**

```
case profiles do
  nil ->
    conn |> put_flash(:info, "No profile found.") |> redirect(to: "/profiles/new") |> halt()
  profiles ->
    assign(conn, :profiles, profiles)
end
```

but I read somewhere that `put_flash` is normally for the controller,
what is the proper way of doing this?

Is there an alternative for `plug`?

Comment: A controller is just another plug.  This isn't a super-common use case -- you're allowed some leeway in how to implement the behavior. A plug/middleware seems like a clean solution.

Comment: please add your comment into answer so that I can accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller is just another plug. This isn't a super-common use case -- you're allowed some leeway in how to implement the behavior. A plug/middleware seems like a clean solution.  At its heart, it isn't all that different from the conditional redirects you see that vary depending on whether a user is logged in or not.